# Pandas keep_default_na=False does not work

Tags: python, excel, pandas

## Issue

I have an Excel file (.xlsx) that contains a sheet with some values equals to '#N/A'.

[image]

When reading the Excel sheet as a DataFrame using pandas, '#N/A' values are interpreted as NaN.

Based on the [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) guide, I expect that '#N/A' can be read 'as is' into the DataFrame by adding the `keep_default_na=False` parameter.

Unfortunately '#N/A' is still interpreted as NaN.

### Code

Here is the code used:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io='TestWorkbook.xlsx',
              sheet_name="Sheet1",
              keep_default_na=False)
```

And the result:

[image]

It seems that `keep_default_na=False` worked on 'N/A' and 'NA' values but not '#N/A'.

## Question

Do you know any workaround to reading '#N/A' as-is into the DataFrame?

Comment: Could you upload your excel sheet somewhere so I can try it?

Comment: @Scotty1- Probably not a good idea to download random files on the internet ;)

Comment: True, but that would have made it easier to try finding a solution. :)

Comment: worth exploring `na_filter=False` instead `keep_default_na=False`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because Excel isn't storing those `#N/A` values in column B as strings. There's a visual *indication* of this if you notice those `#N/A` cells are centre-aligned.

Pandas won't differentiate between different types of Excel errors: `#N/A` / `#NUM!` / `#NAME?` / `#VALUE!` etc will all come through as `NaN`. Which makes sense, there isn't a parallel Python/C type for every Excel error.

So, in short, with `pd.read_excel` there's nothing you can do except override *all* errors with a specific string, e.g. `'#N/A'`, and lose all knowledge of the specific error type(s) you find by opening the file in Excel:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].fillna('#N/A')
```

The alternative is to *force* Excel to use text values, e.g. by inserting into an Excel cell:

```
=TEXT("#N/A", "")
```

Then read using `pd.read_excel` with `keep_default_na=False`. This seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Oh right. But why is my solution working on my computer? Is there some Excel-internals for defining NA-values depending on the region  or version number of Excel? I'm using a german version of excel 2010 and `#N/A` is definitely stored as a string even when the format of the cell is chosen as number format...

Comment: @Scotty1-, No idea. Neither of your solutions work for me.

Comment: Will not that `fillna('#N/A')` will replace all Nan to `#N/A` regardless if its NaN or #N/A

Comment: @pygo, No, `fillna` will only replace `NaN` with `'#N/A'`. It won't replace `'#N/A'` because those are strings (not `NaN`).

Comment: @jpp: Strange... Then it must be something with the regional display style of NA-values in Excel... @pygo: This would replace all NA-values with `'#N/A'`, but as far as I understood the question, Jason wants to keep the different "notations" for the NA-values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @jpp. The '#N/A' values in my example were typed into the cells and not a result of Excel formula calculation error.

So, I changed B3 format to 'Text' instead of 'General' and it was still centre-aligned. I double clicked the B3 (as if to edit it) and click another random cell (as if I'd finished editing) and the cell turns into left-aligned. Running the python codes again yielded the result that I wanted, that is '#N/A' is not interpreted as NaN.

But I need this to be automated as I am processing large quantity of Excel files. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Jason100, That's an Excel issue. In Excel, you would need to force into text via `=TEXT("#N/A", "")`. Try that and it'll come through as text with `keep_default_na=False`.

Comment: @Scotty1- You are right. I want to preserve the original data from Excel whatever the value is.

Comment: @pygo- How will that preserve the '#N/A'? Specifying it in `na_values` is basically telling pandas to interpret '#N/A' as NaN.

Comment: Okay, So, you want na_values to be in original shape then @jpp solution should work.

Comment: @pygo Agreed. The only challenge is it’s cumbersome to manually search and convert the ‘#N/A’ values before reading into pandas.

Comment: @jpp Do you know if this issue only applies to pandas? If so, any idea how to read data from Excel while preserving the actual data?

Comment: @Jason100, Correct but i do not see anything for this as an easy approach into pandas documentation but worth to draw this into pandas developers attention  so post processing can be easy :-)

Comment: @Jason100, I'm afraid I don't know, you can try other libraries such as `openpyxl` or `xlrd`. But probably outside the scope of a question on Pandas, it's possibly a good question to ask separately.

Comment: I hope you alreday looked around but in case worth checking on [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values)

Comment: jpp & pygo - Will check them out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    io='TestWorkbook.xlsx',
    sheet_name="Sheet1",
    na_values='', keep_default_na=False
)
```

If you specify `keep_default_na=False`, the values given in `na_values` will overwrite the default NA-values. Since your NA-values are in the default NA-values, you need to specify some `na_values='some_dummy_na_value'` the use this to overwrite the default NA-values.

If you for example want to keep interpreting `N/A` and `NA` as NA-values (while keeping `#N/A` as a string), you can specify them in the `na_values` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    io='TestWorkbook.xlsx',
    sheet_name="Sheet1",
    na_values=['N/A', 'NA'], keep_default_na=False
)
```

Comment: No luck. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. But it should work. I just tried it... In my case `#N/A` is loaded into the df as a string `'#N/A'`.

Comment: That's odd. I don't suppose my operating system and installed libraries have anything to do with it. I'll set up another virtual environment and with new installation of pandas and other necessary libraries before trying again.